# owncloud server access work over HTTP but fail over HTTPS

Tags: nginx

Following some tutorials and with lot of trials and errors I have been able to setup an owncloud server on my raspberry Pi.

Everything works fine if I connect over HTTP but I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` when I try to connect over HTTPS. Nothing appear in nginx log related to this failure.

Have been searching for 2 days now and I can't find anything that fit my problem. Hope someone here can push me in the right direction.

Here is my current site configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/html/owncloud;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  xxxx.no-ip.org/;
location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
}
location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
    return 404;
}
location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    return 404;
}
location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+|core/templates/40[34])\.php(?:$|/) {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_request_buffering off;
}
location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    index index.php;
}
location ~* \.(?:svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
    access_log off;
}


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.no-ip.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.no-ip.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

# Redirect non-https traffic to https
# if ($scheme != "https") {
#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: I see your using Let’s Encrypt, i assume, you have verified the certificate was successfully created?

Comment: Yes, everything went fine regarding certificate creation